# Xcode 6.1.1 autolayout error

Tags: objective-c, xcode

After checking the "Use Autolayout" option, I am getting the following error:

```
Alignment constraints with different attributes with Xcode versions prior to 5.1
```

Why am I getting this error? What should I do to use autolayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you were using old version project.

**General** -> **Deployment Target** -> DropDownlist choose Deployment Target above 5.1

Edit:

[image]

Comment: This didn't work. The project was developed in prior to version iOS 6.0. When the project is opened in Xcode 6.1.1, then the error is started to appear. Within storyboard file,there are below entries:<deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <development version="5000" identifier="xcode"/>        
        <capability name="Alignment constraints to the first baseline" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
        <capability name="Alignment constraints with different attributes" minToolsVersion="5.1"/>
        <capability name="Constraints to layout margins" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>

Comment: Seem like some constrains is different while update the version.

Comment: How can I resolve the constraints? Please help as I am new to iOS. Also when Use Auto Layout is unchecked, build succeeds.

Comment: @TishaAnand Since I am not sure what's wrong with your constrain.

Comment: @TishaAnand try changing the Xcode version in interface Builder, see my edit.